# How to change the color of Time_range_picker

Tags: flutter, dart, timepicker

I want to change the color blue in this time picker, for example I want to change the color of OK and CANCEL button and AM/PM and time selection to red
I added a screenshot for the time picker and I took it from [her](https://github.com/trashfeed/simple_time_range_picker), I downloaded the files to change the color but I only be able to change the color of the underlined time (in red in the screenshot)
[time_picker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfSpM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change the style of `TimePicker` you can change it in ThemeData:

```
 MaterialApp(
     theme:
        ThemeData(
           timePickerTheme: TimePickerThemeData(
              hourMinuteColor: Colors.green,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        )),)
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I tried it but I got this error ->Error: The getter 'Colors' isn't defined for the class 'TimePickerThemeData'. and the run stopes

Comment: are you changing the theme in `MaterialApp`?

Comment: try with `Color`   -- `Color.fromARGB(255,200,234,234)`

Comment: I found out that the error is from another reason and your code Works thank you! but I still would not know how to change the AM/PM and hour and minute selection color

Comment: these are all the properties you can customize -https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimePickerThemeData-class.html